# How can I stream WMV files to my iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, streaming, wmv

Is it possible to stream a Windows Media Video (.wmv) file via the web into my iPhone application?

If so, how?  Are there libraries out there that can enable this?

Comment: Why closing? This is a valid question, I think.

Comment: @Till - At first, it read like he might be asking for an application that could do this.  I've reworded the question to make it clear that he's looking for a programmatic solution.

Comment: @Brad good point and thank you for editing,

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to transcode the files.  iOS devices do not natively suport WMV file format or the video codecs within.  (E.g.: WMV2, WVC1, *et al*.)

[iLounge: The Complete Guide to iPod, Apple TV and iPhone Video Formats](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/the-complete-guide-to-ipod-video-formats-and-display-resolutions/) is a great source of information for working out what containers and codecs you should target.  Read it carefully.  While iOS devices support MPEG-4/h264 videos, they do not support any and all codec options.  That means you could encode a valid h264 video, which will play on your PC, but won't play on an iOS device.

I'd recommend re-encoding from the source material if you can.  [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) + [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) are great open source tools for accomplishing this, although they will require a degree of technical sophistication.  [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is another solid option.