# Conversion of .wmv file to .mp4 programmatically in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios6

I have played a mp4 file using Objective-C code, but it's not supporting for .wmv files. How can I convert it?

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie-1" ofType:@"mp4" inDirectory:nil];

// Create custom movie player
moviePlayer = [[[CustomMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithPath:path] autorelease];

// Show the movie player as modal
[self presentModalViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES];
```

by above code I have done for mp4.

Answer (score 2):

If you can figure out [how to build and incorporate the FFMPEG library into your iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061086/building-ffmpeg-library-for-ios6-0-armv7-processor), you should be able to convert a .wmv formatted files or data into .mp4 that you can use.

Comment: thank u,, i need another help, tel me how to play .wmv in ios sdk using objective c coding

Comment: there might be [related questions that have useful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401773/how-can-i-stream-wmv-files-to-my-ios-application) that can help you with this.